# URL to compose a message in Gmail with attached files

Tags: vba, email, hyperlink, gmail, attachment

I'm writing a VBA program to send an Excel file to Gmail through Chrome.

I don't use a CDO command because, since the last year, you need to activate "Less secure apps" on your gmail account. The users will not agreed to that.

Thus, I try to open Chrome, and write an email, using this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com
```

How do I add a file with that method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an URL to do that, instead use [[image]gmail-api](/questions/tagged/gmail-api).